# Reading a specific pattern of a txt file in C

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, queue, fgets

I have a txt file with this pattern:

```
11/01/2010: did not pass the test! :(
5
10/02/2010: not even this time I passed it! >:(
2
16/04/2010: is the third time I retake this exam!!! >:@
1
20/05/2024: finally passed it! :D 
14
```

I have to put every instance in the file in a queue data structure so defined

```c
struct post {
    char msg[257];
    int n_like;
};

struct feed {
    struct post* storage;
    int busy;
};

void init(struct feed* queue) {
    queue->storage = malloc(sizeof(struct post) * N_QUEUE); //N_QUEUE = 4
    queue->busy = 0;
}
```

To do this I tried this function, where I read the first whole line using `fgets()` and then the number below with `fscanf()`. Then storing everythin through `append()`:

```c
int append(struct feed* queue, struct post s) {
    if (queue->busy >= N_QUEUE) return handle_err(FULL);
    queue->storage[queue->busy] = s;
    queue->busy++;
    return OK;
}

struct post pop(struct feed* queue) {
    if (queue->busy <= 0) handle_err(EMPTY);
    struct post s = queue->storage[0];
    for (int i=0; i<queue->busy-1; i++) {
        queue->storage[i] = queue->storage[i+1];
    }
    queue->busy--;
    return s;
}

int load_user_from_file(char* filename, struct feed* queue) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) return handle_err(FILE_ERR);
    
    struct post s;
    while (fgets(s.msg, 257, fp) != NULL) {
            while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &s.n_like) == 1) {
                append(&(*queue), s);
            }
        }
    return OK;
}
```

main:

```c
int main() {
    struct feed queue;
    init(&queue);
    char* filename = "user42.txt"; 
    load_user_from_file(filename, &queue);

    return 0;
}
```

If I let the program run I get, of course, empty strings and zeros. Instead by including the `handle_err()`, which just triggers errors on screen and exits, I get a full stack error.

```c
int handle_err(int errno) {
    switch (errno) {
        case FILE_ERR:
            printf("\nerror (%d): could not write/read the file\n\n", FILE_ERR);
            break;
        case EMPTY:
            printf("\nerror (%d): queue is empty\n\n", EMPTY);
            break;
        case FULL:
            printf("\nerror (%d): queue reached its full space\n\n", FULL);
            break;
        default: printf("\nunknown error occurred\n\n");
    }
    exit(FALSE);
}
```

I'm pretty sure there's something wrong in the `load_user_from_file` function.

Comment: The file content is not clear. Do you have 2 lines as you show for each entry? Or do you have a number of lines with data+text and one final line with that number? Or one line with date+text and multiple lines with just that single integer?

Comment: You should not mix `fgets` and `fscanf`. The latter will leave the newline in the input buffer and the following `fgets` will  treat that as an empty line. You could better read every line with `fgets` and parse the content of that line with `sscanf`.

Comment: Sidenote: `int errno` You should not redefine identifiers defined in the standard C library.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. The code of this [mre] should be in a single code block. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste. You can, however, post additional snippets of your code in code blocks in order to explain them (as you are doing now), but if you decide to do that, this should be done in addition, not instead of, a [mre] in a single code block.

Comment: Your code is way too incomplete to tell a lot about your error. Your code never calls your error handler indicating a full stack. Please provide a MCVE[https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve]

Comment: @Gerhardh I updated the question with the whole file content. As you guessed it's a string and an int on two different lines. This is why I thought using `fgets()` for the string first and then `fscanf()` for the int in the new line. But I already knew it wasn't the best solution .

Comment: `while (fscanf(fp, ...` That will read the single integer in that line and also read the first part of your date in the next line. Clearly not what you want.

Comment: Do you want us to guess what `N_QUEUE` might be? For the file content you show, you will call `append` 7 times.

Comment: I'm sorry about the incompletance of my code, I just don't want the question to be too long to read.
@Gerhardh This was the problem, I updated `N_QUEUE` to the number of times the function gets actually called, 7 (which of course I didn't think about. Believing the function would get called every two lines in the txt file). Doing this it looks like it works just fine.

Comment: I don't think it works just fine. As you did not tell us what behaviour you want to achieve, it might be fine but I guess it is not. See my answer

Comment: It doesn't. But at least I'm getting a little closer to understand what's wrong.
What I need to get from my code depends only on the function storing correctly the data, every type of conceivable manipulation of the data depends on this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254042/discussion-between-gerhardh-and-angelo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your code is not complete, this is clearly wrong:

```c
    while (fgets(s.msg, 257, fp) != NULL) {
            while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &s.n_like) == 1) {
                append(&(*queue), s);
            }
        }
```

With the given input file that will result in more entries than you want to.

With

```
11/01/2010: did not pass the test! :(
5
10/02/2010: not even this time I passed it! >:(
2
```

The `fscanf` will first parse `5` and then also `10`, leaving `"/02/2010: not even this time I passed it! >:(\n"` for the next entry.

In total you will append 7 structs instead of 4.

As you have a clear relation of one line with date+text and one line with that integer, it does not make any sense to use `fscanf` in a loop.

Try something like this:

```c
    while (fgets(s.msg, 257, fp) != NULL)
    {
        char buf[100];
        if ( (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp) != NULL) 
          && (sscanf(buf, "%d", &s.n_like) == 1)
        {
           append(&(*queue), s);
        }
        else
        {   // Adjust error handling for your needs.
            exit(1);
        }
    }
```